# MongoDB replicaset slow startup

Tags: mongodb

I have a replicaset with smallfiles enabled, now I'm suffering from the huge time one instance take to start/restart, db files count is something like 2500 files and it take almost an hour to load it and start up, any suggestion how I can speed this process up ?

Comment: Why did you enable small files?

Comment: well by this time my db's were smaller and it made sense, but now it's huge, can I revert back without losing data ?

Comment: What version of MongoDB are you running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performance should improve if your run your Mongo instance with `smallfiles` disabled. As this is a replica set, you can just shut down your instance, delete all your data files and journals, and then restart your service. After restarting, the data will be synced again with the primary instance. This initial sync may take some time, however, any subsequent sync should be a lot faster.